# Can an encrypted SD Card be recovered?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, encryption, lg

My hopes aren't very high for this one but here's how my problem goes:

I am using an LG V10. Over the summer, its motherboard decided to die and it was replaced. Therefore the external SD card I used and encrypted on my old motherboard is now inaccessible :/ Is there any way to reach its contents?

If android devs really didn't come up with a way to decrypt an SD card on another device than the one its encrypted on, then there's no point in using encryption at all and maybe even no point in preferring android either..

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What kind of encryption are we talking about here: adoptable storage (using the card as internal storage), or something else? In the former case: as your PCB got replaced, the original "internal storage chip" is gone as well. So even with root powers, there's no way to retrieve the encryption key – no chances in that case.

Comment: @Izzy Well, I am not sure about the technical term, but I was using it as additional storage in addition to the default internal storage. So it was something like 32 gb internal + 120gb external sd (this is the one I talk about)

Comment: Something like what's described in our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info) (with screenshots)?